# Qt build static library for all architectures

Tags: android, c++, qt

I try build static library for Android (*.a). My pro-file:

```
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

ANDROID_ABIS = armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64

SOURCES += \
    untitled3.cpp

HEADERS += \
    untitled3.h
```

Files untitled3.cpp and untitled3.h very simple. When I build project I get the only one library *.a, but expected get four libs for all architectures: armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64

When I build at first, compilation finished with error:

```
10:13:57: Running steps for project untitled3...
10:13:57: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\range\Documents\untitled3\untitled3.pro -spec android-clang "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" ANDROID_ABIS="armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64"
Info: creating stash file C:\Users\range\Documents\andr_out\.qmake.stash
WARNING: Targets of builds 'Armeabi-v7a' and 'Arm64-v8a' conflict: libuntitled3.a.
10:13:57: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
10:13:57: Starting: "C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" -f C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out/Makefile qmake_all
make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
10:13:57: The process "C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited normally.
10:13:57: Starting: "C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" -j12
C:/Users/range/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make -f Makefile.Armeabi-v7a all
C:/Users/range/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make -f Makefile.Arm64-v8a all
C:/Users/range/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make -f Makefile.X86 all
C:/Users/range/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.0.6113669/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make -f Makefile.X86_64 all
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out'
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -g -marm -O0 -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\untitled3 -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\include\QtCore -Iarmeabi-v7a -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\mkspecs\android-clang -o armeabi-v7a\untitled3.obj ..\untitled3\untitled3.cpp
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out'
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -g -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\untitled3 -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\include\QtCore -Iarm64-v8a -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\mkspecs\android-clang -o arm64-v8a\untitled3.obj ..\untitled3\untitled3.cpp
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out'
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -target i686-linux-android21 -mstackrealign -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -g -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\untitled3 -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\include\QtCore -Ix86 -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\mkspecs\android-clang -o x86\untitled3.obj ..\untitled3\untitled3.cpp
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out'
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -target x86_64-linux-android21 -fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -g -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\untitled3 -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\include\QtCore -Ix86_64 -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\android\mkspecs\android-clang -o x86_64\untitled3.obj ..\untitled3\untitled3.cpp
del libuntitled3.a
del libuntitled3.a
del libuntitled3.a
del libuntitled3.a
ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп  ©вЁ C:\Users\range\Documents\andr_out\libuntitled3.a
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar cqs libuntitled3.a arm64-v8a\untitled3.obj
ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп  ©вЁ C:\Users\range\Documents\andr_out\libuntitled3.a
ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп  ©вЁ C:\Users\range\Documents\andr_out\libuntitled3.a
ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп  ©вЁ C:\Users\range\Documents\andr_out\libuntitled3.a
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar cqs libuntitled3.a armeabi-v7a\untitled3.obj
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar cqs libuntitled3.a x86\untitled3.obj
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar cqs libuntitled3.a x86_64\untitled3.obj
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ranlib libuntitled3.a
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ranlib libuntitled3.a
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-ranlib: libuntitled3.a: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [Makefile.Arm64-v8a:67: libuntitled3.a] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:62: arm64-v8a-all] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out'
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-ranlib libuntitled3.a
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib libuntitled3.a
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ranlib: unable to rename 'libuntitled3.a'; reason: File exists
make[1]: *** [Makefile.X86_64:67: libuntitled3.a] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out'
make: *** [Makefile:90: x86_64-all] Error 2
C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android-ranlib: unable to rename 'libuntitled3.a'; reason: File exists
make[1]: *** [Makefile.X86:67: libuntitled3.a] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:76: x86-all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out'
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/range/Documents/andr_out'
10:13:58: The process "C:\Users\range\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled3 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 (Clang Qt 5.14.1 for Android))
When executing step "Make"
10:13:58: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

When I build at second, compilation finished successfully, but in output dir I find one *.a - lib:
[image: 6543a40d-136b-42c6-a0c4-8a8c3f2b59ab-image.png]

In folders armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64 exist only *.obj - files, but not exist .*a - files.
My question: how correct build static library (*.a) for android for **all** (4) architectures?
P.S.: Qt version for Android: 5.14.1; Qt Creator version: 4.11.0, based on Qt version: 5.14.0

Comment: Were you able to build static libraries of Qt for android?

Comment: @tunafish24 yes, I created 4 another projects

Answer (score 1):

have you tried building 4 seperate projects for each android architecture (a .pro for each architecture) to see what the result is? it’s obviously not ideal when the project gets larger, but from diagnostics point of view it’s worth a try.

Comment: Amazing, but this is working. But this is not convenient. There is additional solutions?

Comment: since it worked using different .pro files, it most likely means it is a syntactic issue. i haven't used qmake in a while so this is just a guess, however maybe try separating the architect identifiers with line breaks, similarly to how the source and header files are laid out, i know qt quite likes this format. you could also try separating the architect identifiers with a comma + space if the previous method didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but nothing solution not working :(